# Can I repent from my friends for stealing. Chatting directly to them on the phone (but not telling them who I am)

Tags: theft

6 years ago, when I was 7 years old I stole for the first time from a friend (best friend now) a few erasers (puzzled shaped) out of jealously and the second time I again thought of stealing from her but didn't do it. Then in the same year I again stole a shiny paperweight from a different friend when she wasn't looking,(from her pocket). I have both their belongings with me and whenever I see them I regret doing the theft. I want to repent from them. So, I wanted to ask whether I can repent from both of them on the phone (messages) and at the same time not tell them who I am? And also can I indirectly return their belongings or should I give out charity (So that they don't know who's apologizing)?

Answer (score 0):

Yallah being a teacher would understand your feelings, everyone experiences what you did at some stage. Most never feel guilt so you’re already on a positive path asking advice. Shows you care for your friend also. Be honest and own up, explain how you feel too. Not only telling your friend about what you did will make you feel better but explaining how you feel emotionally will make your relationship stronger, build trust.
Same thing will happen to you one day and you’ll be a better teacher for having experienced it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you do all this openly. This will give you full relief and I do not think that it will harm your friendship. Your friends can forgive you only if they know who you are. And Allah will forgive you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn’t share your sins with anyone except to repent and ask forgiveness to Allah (swt)

In Christianity there is priests to repent and confess your sins to but islam prescribes you to only share those sins with your creator ,repent and ask for forgiveness and do not repeat .

Now out of guilt you share your sins to your friend they may not view you the way they did before . All merciful and forgiving is Allah (swt) mankind will judge and prosecute you. You should also never open everything about you to a friend . One day they might use information against you . I’m not saying don’t be good friend or good relationship . Open your heart to only Allah (swt) fully . Not to friends or someone who might be dear to you now. That relationship can change.